# HTML sub-pages (using a domain)

Tags: javascript, html

I've been thinking about purchasing a domain and putting a website on it, but I'm not sure how I would add sub-pages. I'm probably using the wrong words, but I'll try to explain what I mean.

For example, the main page is `stackoverflow.com`. When you go to another page, it goes to `stackoverflow.com/questions`. Is this achieved using Javascript, or is it set up manually where you link an HTML file to the sub-page?

I'm not too sure where to start here, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to set up a website with multiple pages is to create a folder for each page and an index.html file for each page. These can then be linked together using HTML anchors or JavaScript code. For detailed instructions on how to do this, I suggest checking out tutorials from W3Schools like [how to make a website](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_make_a_website.asp)

Comment: Unsure why you would want to create a folder for each page

Comment: you can of course create a file per page and link those up to ex: questions.html. But the resulting url would not be like the example stackoverflow.com/questions but be like stackoverflow.com/questions.html